# AsyncHttpClient koushikdutta "Cannot Resolve method GetString"

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, androidasync-koush

Currently implementing some example code based on the https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync lib, getting unresolved method for

".getString"
".getJSONObject"
and
".getJSONArray"

Gradle is in sync and i have ran "invalidate cache and restart"

Dep added to Grandle.

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.2.1'
```

Error
[image: Error]

Suggestions i am getting from IDE starting with 'get'
[image]

Suggestions? Is the lib examples old? Dep is wrong?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Can't figure it out.